# Wanted: A rather large DEM

Tags: data, dem

I am looking for a rather large DEM --- on the trillion cell scale --- to run some tests on.

So far, I have found:

- 200 billion cells: The [SRTM Global Dataset](http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/SRTM/SRTMGL1.003/2000.02.11/) 30m DEM
- 120 billion cells: The [National Elevation Dataset](ftp://rockyftp.cr.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Elevation/13/IMG/) 10m DEM (higher resolutions have incomplete spatial coverage)
- 70 billion cells: The [PAMAP Lidar 1m DEM](ftp://pamap.pasda.psu.edu/pamap_lidar/cycle1/DEM/)

Are there any publically-available DEMs, which are not stored in an Arc Geodatabase format, which meet or exceed the 1 trillion cell threshold?

Comment: Why not just resample?

Comment: @Vince: that's an excellent idea that, for some reason, hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: If you really want it http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey has over 11TB of Lidar data (2m,1m, 50cm and some 25cm res) An Example of the detail (in raster format) is http://www.loach.me.uk/Lidar/#17/51.88563/0.93482